# How to combine duplicate element of an array of objects into one using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arrayobject

I'm not familiar with javascript and I don't know how to search for this problem. Here I've explained briefly about my problem.
Below is the data from which I've to find out the similar entries in the data and combine them as one object.
This is my data:

```
var myArr = [{
        "Company": "Samsung",
        "model": "Galaxy S2",
        "screen_size": "5.5"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Samsung",
        "model": "Galaxy S3",
        "screen_size": "5.5"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Samsung",
        "model": "Galaxy S4",
        "screen_size": "5.5"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Xiaomi",
        "model": "Redmi 2",
        "screen_size": "4.7"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Xiaomi",
        "model": "Redmi 4",
        "screen_size": "5"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Xiaomi",
        "model": "Redmi Note 4",
        "screen_size": "5.5"
    }
]
```

I want to combine all the duplicate entries in the array. So, my outcome of this data should be like this:

```
[{
    "Company": "Samsung",
    "models": [{
        "Galaxy S2": {
            "screen_size": "5.5"
        }
    }, {
        "Galaxy S3": {
            "screen_size": "5.6"
        }
    }, {
        "Galaxy S4": {
            "screen_size": "5.7"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "Company": "Xiaomi",
    "models": [{
        "Redmi 2": {
            "screen_size": "4.7"
        }
    }, {
        "Redmi 4": {
            "screen_size": "5"
        }
    }, {
        "Redmi Note 4": {
            "screen_size": "5.5"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Somebody, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your object using `array#reduce` on the `Company` key in an object and extract all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var myArr=[{ "Company": "Samsung", "model": "Galaxy S2", "screen_size": "5.5" }, { "Company": "Samsung", "model": "Galaxy S3", "screen_size": "5.5" }, { "Company": "Samsung", "model": "Galaxy S4", "screen_size": "5.5" }, { "Company": "Xiaomi", "model":"Redmi 2", "screen_size": "4.7" }, { "Company": "Xiaomi", "model": "Redmi 4", "screen_size": "5" }, { "Company": "Xiaomi", "model": "Redmi Note 4", "screen_size": "5.5" } ],
    result = Object.values(myArr.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.Company] = r[o.Company] || {'Company': o.Company, 'Models' : []};
      r[o.Company]['Models'].push({[o.model]:{'screen_size' : o.screen_size}});
      return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  { first_name: 'Hamo', last_name: 'Muradyan', subject: 'Chemistry', score: 35 },
  { first_name: 'Aren', last_name: 'Abelyan', subject: 'Math', score: 90 },
  { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', subject: 'Geometry', score: 24 },
  { first_name: 'Vardges', last_name: 'Gasparyan', subject: 'Math', score: 10 },
  { first_name: 'Hambardzum', last_name: 'Simonyan', subject: 'Astronomy', score: 80 },
  { first_name: 'Kamo', last_name: 'Hakhverdyan', subject: 'Physics', score: 21 },
  { first_name: 'Ashot', last_name: 'Vardanyan', subject: 'Chemistry', score: 28 },
  { first_name: 'Vardges', last_name: 'Mnoyan', subject: 'Physics', score: 100 },
  { first_name: 'Ruzanna', last_name: 'Sargsyan', subject: 'Astronomy', score: 98 },
  { first_name: 'Hasmik', last_name: 'Kchepyan', subject: 'Math', score: 99 },
  { first_name: 'Ani', last_name: 'Hovhannisyan', subject: 'Psychology', score: 100 },
  { first_name: 'Kima', last_name: 'Ghazaryan', subject: 'Math', score: 88 },
  { first_name: 'Karen', last_name: 'Manukyan', subject: 'Psychology', score: 1 },
  { first_name: 'Manuk', last_name: 'Tserunyan', subject: 'Astronomy', score: 65 },
];

function getResult () {
  let obj = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj[data[i].subject] = obj[data[i].subject] || {subject: data[i].subject, persons: []};
    obj[data[i].subject].persons.push(data[i]);
  };
  
  return Object.values(obj);
};

getResult();
```